# Increment Date by One Day in Formula - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Captured Dataset]

I want to have separate two columns that each row has a date, and another row containing total sale of the date.

I want my formula to increment the date by a day and automatically sum every transactions in that day.

I apologize if my explanation is awful.

Comment: Excel has a `Subtotals` feature for that.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use Sumif To Sum Value See  Bellow Mention Screenshot
=SUMIF(A:B,D2,B:B)